# Discrete State Space eigenvalues: approach unity as loop rate increases?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, discrete-time

Say I have a stable discrete State Space control system (feedback system) of the standard formulation:

x[k+1] = Ad*x[k] + Bd + u [k].

Why do the |discrete eigenvalues| **approach** the unit circle (z = 1) as sampling rate increases? I would have thought that due to a more stable system, the stability margin (eig distance from unit circle) would **increase** as sampling rate increases, and so

|discrete eig|-->0, ie more stable.

**Background**:

Ad and Bd are discrete matrices, discretized with a sampling rate Ts.
Note: Since this is a feedback system, Ad includes the feedback mechanism, eg Ad = Ad_openLoop - Bd * Kd, where Kd could be eg. a discretized gain eg from Matlab's lqrd().

**I build up the state space with varying loop rates to check for stability as a function of loop rate.** I'd like to check stability by looking at the eigenvalues the system as the loop rate increases (Ts becomes smaller).

The eigenvalues of the continuous version of this system are stable.
The eigenvalues of the discrete version of this system are also stable, but for smaller loop rates (larger Ts), the eigenvalues are closer to the origin.
For larger loop rates approaching inf (Ts --> 0), the eigenvalues approach 1: |eig| --> 1

This seems counterintuitive.
I would have thought faster rates would mean a more stable system, so larger eig margin, ie eig approaches origin (since |disc eig| >= 1 imply marginal stability or instability)

What am i missing conceptually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discretized system becomes trivial as the sample period $T \to 0.$ For now assume you have determined the controller and the loop is closed. Then the system takes the form,

$$\dot{x} = A\, x.$$

The exact discretization of this system with sample period $T$ is,

$$x(k) = \exp(T A)\, x(k-1).$$

It is straightforward to compute (use the Taylor series definition) that, as $T\to 0,$ we have that $\exp(T A) \to I$. The discrete time system matrix $\exp(T A)$ converges to a matrix with only 1 as the eigenvalues. This should not be surprising: if you decrease the sample period to zero, the "next sample" is necessarily equal to the current sample. This is what you are observing. If you instead computed the quantity

$$\frac{x(k) - x(k-1)}{T}$$

and see how that changes as $T\to 0$ you will end up finding it converges to $A x(k-1)$ which is what you actually expected. Fundamentally the issue here is that a discretized system matrix computes how you go from one state to the next while the continuous-time system matrix computes the rate of change at a given point.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. You're saying that the discretized matrix Ad doesn't have the same stability representation as cts A, because Ad is NOT the state evolution as A was: instead, Ad is incremental changes, so approach unity as Rs --> 0. Thank you. So then: how can stability be checked with discretized closed loop matrices?

Comment: If you have a discretized system, you just need to check that the eigenvalues are in the unit disc. Then the discrete time system *is* stable implying that, at least, your samples will tend to the zero as you'd expect. Whether or not there are higher order harmonics so that the continuous system results in unbounded oscillations even though the discretized system is stable requires analysis of the original continuous time system with your discrete time controller.

Comment: Thanks. "your samples will tend to the zero as you'd expect" I was assuming that as well; but just as with continuous-time controllers, margins say how much leeway there is for stability. I was looking for the comparable strategy with discretized versions, eg. how stability margin changes with sampling rate (which I can't check on the continuous system...since it's continuous :) )

Comment: That is a great idea since we want to know what the slowest sample rate is before losing stability. The issue here is that the sampling rate is not a property of the discrete-time system, but a property of the interplay between the discrete- and cts-time system; i.e., how you go from cts- to discrete-time. So you have to work in cts-time to see how the sample rate affects stability characteristics. Hence you cannot evaluate that margin in discrete time.

Comment: I see. "So you have to work in cts-time to see how the sample rate affects stability characteristics" How is this done?

Comment: @PB for a linear plant with a zero-order hold, the condition is simple. The plant's (cts-time) A matrix must not have eigenvalues with imaginary part that are integer multiples of the sample frequency (i.e. $j\,2\pi k/h$ where $h$ is the period), and the difference between any two eigenvalues must also not be such a multiple. The precise condition is in Section 8 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/9.1310). this is only for linear systems.

Comment: Thank you :) This was very helpful.